# Spark Cassandra Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, streaming

i want to save data from spark streaming to cassandra using scala maven project. this is the code that save data to cassandra table

```
import org.apache.maventestsparkproject._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._

object SparkCassandra {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

     val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
         .setAppName("KakfaStreamToCassandra").setMaster("local[*]")
         .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
         .set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042")

    val topics = "fayssal1,fayssal2"

     val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))

     val topicsSet = topics.split(",").toSet
     val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)
     val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)

     val lines = messages.map(_._2)

     val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))

     val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1L)).reduceByKey(_ + _)

     wordCounts.saveToCassandra(keysspace, table, SomeColumns("word", "count"))

     ssc.awaitTermination()

     ssc.start()
}
}
```

the project is builting successfly, this is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.apache.maventestsparkproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>testmavenapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>testmavenapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
       <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
       <spark.version>1.6.2</spark.version>
       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>




  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
         <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
         <version>${spark.version}</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
         <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
         <version>${spark.version}</version>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
     </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-rc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-rc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

but when i run this commande:

```
scala -cp /home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/target/testmavenapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala
```

i get the following errors look like this:

```
home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:1: error: object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.maventestsparkproject._
           ^
/home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:2: error: object datastax is not a member of package com
import com.datastax.spark.connector.streaming._
           ^
/home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:3: error: object datastax is not a member of package com
import com.datastax.spark.connector.SomeColumns
           ^
/home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:5: error: object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
           ^
/home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:6: error: object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
           ^
/home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:7: error: object apache is not a member of package org
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._
           ^
/home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:12: error: not found: type SparkConf
     val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                             ^
/home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:19: error: not found: type StreamingContext
     val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))
                       ^
/home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:19: error: not found: value Seconds
     val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(5))
                                                   ^
/home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:22: error: not found: value brokers
     val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)
                                                                         ^
/home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:23: error: not found: value KafkaUtils
     val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
                        ^
/home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:23: error: not found: type StringDecoder
     val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
                                                                      ^
/home/darif/TestProject/testmavenapp/src/main/java/org/apache/maventestsparkproject/SparkCassandra.scala:23: error: not found: type StringDecoder
     val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
                                                                                     ^
13 errors found
```

i am using :

```
 Scala 2.11.8
 Spark 1.6.2
 Kafka Client APIs 0.8.2.11
 Cassandra 3.9
 Datastax Spark-Cassandra Connector compatible with Spark 1.6.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The classpath for your application has not been set up correctly. It is recommend in various places to use `spark-submit` as your launcher as it will setup the vast majority of the classpath. Third party dependencies would be set using --packages.

- [Datastax Example](https://github.com/datastax/SparkBuildExamples)
- [Spark Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

That said you could achieve the same result by custom setting various things in your Spark Conf as well as manually setting the classpath to include all of the Spark, DSE, and Kafka libraries.